# Date in the PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a procedure that takes two parameters (from and to dates - ie. 2022-03-01 - 2022-03-12).

What I need to do is on the second insert if there is same date inserted twice, it should not be shown in table, there should only be error message using DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE.

The other thing I need to do is if there are non-existent dates are entered (ie. 2022-01-01 - 2022-01-15), fill in the table up to the first or last filled date, depending on whether the entered dates are smaller or larger than the existing dates.

The code I tried:

```
 CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE P_dates (p_start  DATE,
                                     p_finish DATE)
IS
  V_DATES DATE := p_start;
  v_exists   NUMBER;
  v_first    DATE;
  v_last     DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT Min(v_dates)
  INTO   v_first
  FROM   table1;
  
  SELECT Max(v_dates)
  INTO   v_last
  FROM   table1;
  
  SELECT Count(*)
  INTO   v_exists
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  v_dates = v_dates;
  
  IF p_finish < v_dates THEN
    dbms_output.Put_line('You can not do this.');
  ELSE
    WHILE v_dates <= p_finish
    LOOP
      
      IF v_exists 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Date '
        || to_char(p_start ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
        ||' is already in the table.');
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO table1
                    (
                                id_dates,
                                dates,
                                year,
                                quartal ,
                                month
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                                to_char(v_dates, 'yyyymmdd'),
                                v_dates ,
                                extract(year FROM v_dates) ,
                                CASE
                                            WHEN extract(month FROM v_dates) IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Q1'
                                            WHEN extract(month FROM v_dates) IN (4,5,6) THEN 'Q2'
                                            WHEN extract(month FROM v_dates) IN (7,8,9) THEN 'Q3'
                                            WHEN extract(month FROM v_dates) IN (10,11,12) THEN 'Q4'
                                END ,
                                extract(month FROM v_dates) ,
                                to_char(v_datum, 'Month')
                    );
        
        v_dates := v_dates + 1;
        IF p_start < v_first p_dates(p_start, v_first - 1);
        ELSIF p_finish v_last THEN
          p_dates(v_last + 1, p_finish);
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: "there should only be error message using DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE" - this sounds strange. Generally errors may be raised with raise_application_error or the procedure may have two out parameters: o_errorcode out number, o_errormessage out varchar2. dbms_output should generally be avoided and is only to be used for debugging purposes during development. Errors may also be logged using a procedure with pragma autonomous_transaction.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems you're overcomplicating thins. A SQL-level `merge` would do, but OK - let's suggest a PL/SQL procedure.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_insert (par_date_from date, par_date_to date)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    merge into table1 a
  5      using (select par_date_from + level - 1 datum
  6             from dual
  7             connect by level <= par_date_to - par_date_from + 1
  8            ) b
  9    on (a.dates = b.datum)
 10    when not matched then insert (id_dates, dates, year, quartal, month)
 11      values (to_char(b.datum, 'yyyymmdd'),
 12              b.datum,
 13              extract(year from b.datum),
 14              'Q' || to_char(b.datum, 'Q'),
 15              extract(month from b.datum)
 16             );
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_insert(date '2022-03-01', date '2022-03-12');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table1;

ID_DATES DATES            YEAR QU      MONTH
-------- ---------- ---------- -- ----------
20220308 2022-03-08       2022 Q1          3
20220306 2022-03-06       2022 Q1          3
20220301 2022-03-01       2022 Q1          3
20220303 2022-03-03       2022 Q1          3
20220307 2022-03-07       2022 Q1          3
20220302 2022-03-02       2022 Q1          3
20220309 2022-03-09       2022 Q1          3
20220311 2022-03-11       2022 Q1          3
20220304 2022-03-04       2022 Q1          3
20220310 2022-03-10       2022 Q1          3
20220305 2022-03-05       2022 Q1          3
20220312 2022-03-12       2022 Q1          3

12 rows selected.
```

Once again, with partially overlapping period:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_insert(date '2022-03-10', date '2022-03-15');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table1 order by dates;

ID_DATES DATES            YEAR QU      MONTH
-------- ---------- ---------- -- ----------
20220301 2022-03-01       2022 Q1          3
20220302 2022-03-02       2022 Q1          3
20220303 2022-03-03       2022 Q1          3
20220304 2022-03-04       2022 Q1          3
20220305 2022-03-05       2022 Q1          3
20220306 2022-03-06       2022 Q1          3
20220307 2022-03-07       2022 Q1          3
20220308 2022-03-08       2022 Q1          3
20220309 2022-03-09       2022 Q1          3
20220310 2022-03-10       2022 Q1          3
20220311 2022-03-11       2022 Q1          3
20220312 2022-03-12       2022 Q1          3
20220313 2022-03-13       2022 Q1          3
20220314 2022-03-14       2022 Q1          3
20220315 2022-03-15       2022 Q1          3

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, there are no duplicates; *missing* rows were added into the table.

---

What's wrong with your procedure? Quite a lot of things, actually. For example:

- the `count` query will return `0` (if table is empty) or total number of rows (if it isn't empty) because you wrongly named local variable `v_dates` as it is equal to column name, so `where` clause evaluates to something like 1 = 1 and filters nothing
- what is `if v_exists 0`? That's invalid; you should check whether date exists in a table, but - `merge` does it in a more *elegant* manner. Besides, is information (that it exists) relevant to anyone? End users won't see that message anyway, unless they run procedure in tool that allows `dbms_output.put_line` to be seen on the screen
- the last `if-then-else` (`if p_start < v_first p_dates(...`) is a mystery to me. `then` keyword is missing; then procedure calls itself, but - why? I just don't understand it.
- loop means row-by-row processing, and that's slow. You won't notice it on small data set, but you will if you handle many rows. Use set-oriented statements (such as `merge`), if possible

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has many issues including:

1. `SELECT Min(v_dates) INTO v_first FROM table1;` uses the PL/SQL variable `v_dates` and not the column name `dates` so you are effectively doing `v_first := v_dates;`.
2. `SELECT Max(v_dates) INTO v_last FROM table1;` uses the PL/SQL variable `v_dates` and not the column name `dates` so you are effectively doing `v_last := v_dates;`.
3. `SELECT Count(*) INTO v_exists FROM table1 WHERE v_dates = v_dates;` filters on `v_dates = v_dates` which is the same as checking if `1 = 1` so all you are ding is counting if there is at least 1 row in the table and not checking if there are any existing rows within the range.
4. `IF p_start < v_first p_dates(p_start, v_first - 1);` is syntactically invalid as there is no `THEN` keyword.

There are more issues and it is easier to just rewrite the procedure.

You can simplify it by using `MERGE` to insert all the values at one time. If you need to output the existing rows then that can be found with a cursor loop.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE P_dates (
  p_start  DATE,
  p_finish DATE
)
IS
  V_DATES DATE := p_start;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT dates
            FROM   table1
            WHERE  dates BETWEEN p_start AND p_finish
            ORDER BY dates)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(
      'Date ' || to_char(r.dates, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' is already in the table.'
    );
  END LOOP;

  MERGE INTO table1 dst
  USING (
    SELECT p_start + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY p_start + LEVEL - 1 <= p_finish
  ) src
  ON (dst.dates = src.dt)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
      id_dates,
      dates,
      year,
      quartal,
      month
    ) VALUES (
      to_char(src.dt, 'yyyymmdd'),
      src.dt,
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM src.dt) ,
      'Q'||TO_CHAR(src.dt, 'Q') ,
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM src.dt)
    );
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tCh7gOJj)

You should also consider changing your table to use virtual columns as all the other columns can be derived from the single `dates` column.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vXamnwG1)